# toggleClass works only at first click (IE, FF)

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my very first question and I'm rarely ask for help before I find the answer myself but this one got me for real.

I have the following:

HTML

```
<!-- This one opens/shows the nav. I should change div to a button tag -->
<div class="menu"><a id="menu-open" class="menu-open" href="#">&#9776;</a></div>
<nav id="navigation" class="navigation">
    <!-- This on closes/hide the nav --> 
    <button type="button" value="Close" class="button-close">
        <a id="menu-close" class="menu-close">X</a>
    </button>
    <h1>User Name</h1>
    <p class="mail"><sec:authentication property="principal.username" /></p>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navigation {
        position: fixed;
        background: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -100;
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
}

.navigation-open {
        z-index: 100;
        display: inherit;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".menu-open").click(function(){
       $(".navigation").toggleClass("navigation-open")                  
    });
    $(".menu-close").click(function(){
       $(".navigation").toggleClass("navigation-open")
    });
});
```

When I hit the a tag with menu-open class it actually shows the nav tag (meaning, I guess, toggleClass is working), but then just after that I hit a tag with menu-close class and no toggling is execute.

This issue happens on IE and FF but not CH

I'm using CH 52, IE 11 and FF 46.

I've already tried:

- Changing jQuery version from 1.x to 3.x
- Using e.stopPropagation() function and redirecting the handling to html

I'd appreciate any help on this one since it's driving me nuts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you have an anchor inside of a button? the handler is bound to the anchor, but presumably it's the button which is being clicked? (unless you actually click on the X)

Comment: Well, I really didn't think about why having an anchor inside a button, probably that button was a div and the anchor still remains. That's bad now that you point it. Nevertheless. anchor and button are the same size and both are like "clickable" elements by definition, but yeah, I should change that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You were actually right about who was the handler. I was making some "inception" of clickable elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button elements shouldn't have an anchor inside them.

Check this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".menu-open").click(function(){
       $(".navigation").toggleClass("navigation-open")                  
    });
    $(".menu-close").click(function(){
       $(".navigation").toggleClass("navigation-open")
    });
});
```

```css
.navigation {
        position: fixed;
        background: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -100;
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
}

.navigation-open {
        z-index: 100;
        display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This one opens/shows the nav. I should change div to a button tag -->
<div class="menu"><a id="menu-open" class="menu-open" href="#">&#9776;</a></div>
<nav id="navigation" class="navigation">
    <!-- This on closes/hide the nav --> 
    <button type="button" value="Close" class="button-close menu-close">
        X
    </button>
    <h1>User Name</h1>
    <p class="mail"><sec:authentication property="principal.username" /></p>
</nav>
```

Comment: Now it's working, but why?. It's because I missed my point in assigning the correct handling to the correct element?. Because I just erase that anchor and voilá, it works!.
P.D.: I can't believe that was it. Damn

Comment: The problem was the since you had the `a` inside the `button` - only a click **exactly** on the `a` triggered your `click` event (and not clicking on the button, somewhere).

Comment: @markite, Will also appreciate a voteup on my answer :)

Comment: Sorry, this is my very first question here :P. I think I can vote up this time :/

Comment: np :) you can do it later on

Comment: *can't, and sure I will later on! :)